# Unpacking a C struct with Pythons struct module

Tags: python, c, struct

I am sending a struct in binary format from C to my python script.

My C struct:

```
struct EXAMPLE {
    float val1;
    float val2;
    float val3;
}
```

How I send it:

```
struct EXAMPLE *ex;
ex->val1 = 5.3f;
ex->val2 = 12.5f;
ex->val3 = 15.5f;

write(fd, &ex, sizeof(struct EXAMPLE));
```

How I recieve:

```
buf = sock.recv(12)
buf = struct.unpack('f f f', buf)
print buf
```

But when I print it out on the python side all I get is random garbage. I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with the struct definition in python but I'm not sure what.

Comment: I suggest checking the byte order you're sending/receiving in

Comment: `ex` is already a pointer, and then you are writing to the address of the pointer.

Comment: Your C struct might have padding, too, which you need to inform Python's unpacking code. Also, I'm not sure what a space in the format does. In any case, what are the actual byte values being sent? What are the byte values being received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
write(fd, &ex, sizeof(struct EXAMPLE));
```

It should be:

```
write(fd, ex, sizeof(struct EXAMPLE));
```